# The building target and min sdk version

Tags: android, api, sdk

I am trying to make an android app. I am struggle at finding the suitable API level for my first app. I also not sure what min ark version is and what should I type in while creating a new project.

Can someone please answer me how to determine the correct API level and also what exactly is min sdk version??

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Minimum SDK version specifies that you application will work on minimum that android version and above. It also helps application to be showed on market. So when you put minimum sdk version like 8, your application will work on minimum android version 8 and above.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to choose the lower that you use in your application to your "minSdkVersion".
Generally I used the minSdkVersion 7 (= Android 2.1 Eclair) to reach a maximum of people. You can find a pie chart [here](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).
When you develop, do not hesitate to increase your minSdkVersion if you used a new API, you can find the API levels for any methods in the Android reference.